# entity_generate process plugin issue with node generation

Tags: migrations

I want to use use entity_generate plugin to create a node for each row of source I'm migrating. I'm getting 'title' source field and want to create a node in some my_content_type, with that title. My migration looks like:

```
  # Field to populate
  my_content_type:

    plugin: entity_generate
    source: title
    entity_type: node
    bundle: my_content_type
    value_key: title
    bundle_key: nid
    values:
      title: title
```

So, I don't have field referencing that node I'm creating - I just want node to be created as a "side effect". But when I run migration I get the error:

**In ContentEntityStorageBase.php line 125:

Missing bundle for entity type node**

I basically tried to adjust example for tags from here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/contrib-process-plugin-entity_generate

..but something isn't right there. Why it's complaining about missing "bundle" parameter, when I provided it?

Answer (score 2):

Got help from @danflanagan8 on drupal slack channel. So, annotation for tags looks like:

```
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "tid",
*     "revision" = "revision_id",
*     "bundle" = "vid",
*     "label" = "name",
*     "langcode" = "langcode",
*     "uuid" = "uuid",
*     "published" = "status",
*   },
```

and for nodes it's like this:

```
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "nid",
*     "revision" = "vid",
*     "bundle" = "type",
*     "label" = "title",
*     "langcode" = "langcode",
*     "uuid" = "uuid",
*     "status" = "status",
*     "published" = "status",
*     "uid" = "uid",
*     "owner" = "uid",
*   },
```

So bundle for taxonomy terms is "vid" and for nodes is "type".
In example migration file for taxonomy term **bundle_key** field has value "**vid**" and by following that logic for node **bundle_key** should have value "**type**".